# Read CSV file per column

Tags: python, csv, reader

I have a dataset containing four columns with the first three columns being positional arguments XYZ and the latter being a certain value at that position. I want to read this file into a `np.array` in a specific way, namely for every number of points `xnodes` I want to read a number of values (lets say 10) from the last column. What I have up until now is this:

```
with open(FilePath, 'rt') as f:

    reader = csv.reader((row for row in f if not row.startswith('#')), skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=' ')

            for i, row in enumerate(reader):

                if i % xnodes == 0:
```

Where `FilePath` is the location of the datafile. Now when the last `if` condition is met, I want to store the 10 values from the last column, starting from index `i` into an array.

With my limited knowledge in Python, I do not know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add a short sample from your csv file and the respective expected result to help me understand your problem.

Comment: You should use Pandas `read_csv()` to read your file. It will be a lot easier to work with your file =) This function will return a `Dataframe()` which behind the scene is a `np.array`.

Comment: 2d dictionary would help you organize it too, that is if you can create a unique key

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you should use Pandas library to work with tables:

```
import pandas as pd

""" your if your csv contains this :
       x    y   z   value
       10   0   0    125
       0   10   0    354
       12  21  32    214"""

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv') # by default the separator is a comma

for item in df.index:
   # do stuff with your column
   print(df.loc[item])
```

Output :

```
x  10
y  0
z  12
value  125
Name: 0, dtype: int64 

x   0
y   10 
z   21
value   214
Name: 1, dtype: int64
etc...
```